# Why is CLL B-Cell leukemia t(12;21) more responsive to chemotherapy?

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer

Chronic Lympoid Leukemia targeting B-Cell (with the particular translocation mutation on chromosome 12 and 21) is known to be more responsive to chemotherapy. Is there a known molecular mechanism for why?